# why jsp engine make class public and final

Tags: jsp

i use a weblogic server.
when i create a jsp file as my.jsp and deploy it and send a request of my.jsp from browser then jsp engine generatea a _my.java file.

my question is why jsp engine makes this class public final

for ex-

```
public final class _my extends jspbase implements staleindicator
{
}
```

my question is why _my.java is `public` and `final`

Answer (score 0):

It is public because a class which is not in the package with it may need to create an instance of it.

It is final because you should not be inheriting from a Generated JSP java class.